# Storage-design for fetched data (globally?) & navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

im new to JavaScript & React (and new to stackoverflow too)  and I hope to get some ideas/ answers regarding the "logic" in implementing data-storage. I have/ had a dev-background in Obj-C / iOS few years back. So some general concepts in web-dev might not be familiar to me.

Hope I'm doing everything correct in my first post, never really used stackoverflow so far :)
So, basically I have a small project with a Sider und Content (using Ant Design Framework). In this project, im trying to figure out, how generell stuff has to be done, like Navigation through the views, data handling and so on.

In one Tab in the SideBar, i'm using a Table (also antd). If you press on one Item, it should show a detail-View with the props of that specific item (later it should be the form for data change/input).

My App.js:

```
<Content style=...> 
          <Switch>   
            
            <Route exact path="/tasks" >
              <TasksTable 
              data={this.state.tasksData} 
              handleOnRowClicked = {this.handleOnRowClicked}
              />
            </Route>
           
            
            <Route exact path="/details"> 
              <TasksDetail currentTask= {this.state.currentDetailTask}/>
            </Route>
              ....
          </Switch>       
        </Content>
```

In the TasksTable-Component:

```
 ...
 const history = useHistory()
 ...
function handleOnRowClicked(record, rowIndex,event) {
  console.log("Clicked on cell", event)
  history.push("/details/")

  props.handleOnRowClicked(record.id)

}


return(
  <Table 
  dataSource={props.data}
  onRow={ (record, rowIndex) => {
    return {
      onClick: event => { 
        handleOnRowClicked(record, rowIndex,event) }
    }
  }
  }
  >
    <Column title="Name" dataIndex="name" key="name" />
    <Column title="Kunde" dataIndex="client_name" key="client_name" />
    <Column title="Fertigstellung bis" dataIndex="completion_date" key="completion_date" />
    <Column title="Hinzugefügt" dataIndex="created" key="created" />
    <Column title="" 
    dataIndex="remove_button" 
    key="remove_button" 
    render={removeButton => {
      return <button key="ButtonKey" onClick={event => handleOnButtonClicked(event)}>Remove</button>
    }}/>

  </Table>  
  )
```

}

**What i want to achive:**

1. When clicked on one row of the table, i want to push another "view"/ Side to show details of selected row. Currently I'm doing this in the TasksTable-Component with history.push(). I'm wondering if this is the correct way of showing (detail-)views? Because I need to call props.myHandleCallbackFunc(selectedItem) in App.js to set a State names "currentlySelected" for then passing this state as prop to the pushed detail view.
   Hope you get my point.
2. As far as I understood, I should use  ...  for automating the navigation-process. Problem is: As I use the Table from antdesign, I need to make this programatically. Thats why I have this workaround (at least it feels like one) with the onRow property... Is this the correct way of using the table? I have the feeling its not.
3. Problem with my workaround: I've rendered a Button into the Cells to deliver a delete-Button.
   Problem there: Even if i click on the Button, it is registered as a click on the row and therefor pushes my detailview... I tried to differentiate with event.target.key but had no success.
4. Is it the right way of holding **all** data fetched by my api in the uppermost component and share it to sup-components via props? How can I update it from subcomponents then? Should every Subcomponent should get a handler via props to call back, when value changed?

Or in other words: Make the http-request from the sub-comp or send the changed data to the App-component and let it then trigger the HTTP-POST-request? I strongly guess its second choice.

Thank you so much, I appreciate every answer. Im trying to get things working since few hours now...
(Sorry for spelling mistakes, english is not my native one).

P.S: Actually I wanted to post this yesterday but took few extra hours for working through the "similar questions"... Still, open questions :D

Robin

Answer (score 0):

Redux is a predictable state container for JavaScript apps.

It helps you write applications that behave consistently, run in different environments (client, server, and native), and are easy to test. On top of that, it provides a great developer experience, such as live code editing combined with a time traveling debugger.

You can use Redux together with React, or with any other view library. It is tiny (2kB, including dependencies), but has a large ecosystem of addons available.
https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started

Comment: OK I will definitely give it a try. But I can't believe, that there is no "easy" and build-in solution for my problems?Thanks!

Comment: you can also use IndexedDB and write wrappers on top of it